# Service-based database file difference

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am creating a C# winform application that is using a .mdf database I am creating and attaching to the project via the Add New -> Service Based Database. I can add the database and and add tables just fine via Visual Studio and programatically. But when I go to view the data in Visual Studio, my data I inserted is not present. I believe this is because of the fact that the .mdf file that Visual Studio sees and reads is in the project folder where as the .mdf file the code modifies is put in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer  the MSDN link : [How to: Manage Local Data Files in Your Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)